# File upload not working despite enctype="multipart/form-data" included in form

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to get a simple file upload to work using PHP in HTML. However, $_FILES['ufile']['name'] doesn't work as expected.

The HTML form.

```html
<form action="parse.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="ufile">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP code.

```php
if (isset($_FILES['ufile']['name'])) {
    echo "<p>" . $_FILES['ufile']['name'] . "</p>";
} else {
    echo "Please choose a file";
}
```

I should be seeing the filename here, but instead I see what's in the else block, "Please choose a file".

Comment: try var_dumping $_FILES to see what it actually holds

Comment: It tells me it's an array size=0 and _empty_

Comment: @Olimar Did you choose a file before submit? Was the file too large?

Comment: then $_FILES isn't being passed correctly - it's possible you exceed the max upload size set in your php.ini file

Comment: I did select a file, and it's 11.4 MB, I don't know if that's too big, my php.ini should be completely default and I don't know the size limit.

Comment: @Olimar Yes, it's a large file. I presume the default setting is `2M` meaning `2MB`. Try this to check the setting value  `echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize');`

Comment: If this was an error with the file size, then $_FILES should still get populated, and you’d find an appropriate error code in there. Please check what `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` contains.

Comment: @vivek_23 Yeah it's 2MB

Comment: @04FS It says "post".

Comment: @Olimar So upload anything below 2MB and you should be good to go. Or, modify the setting and restart the server and everything would be normal again.

Comment: @vivek_23 I tried doing so and nothing's changed

Comment: @Olimar We would need more context. What did you change and what is still not working?

Comment: @04FS If I don't select a file I do not get an empty array as you said, so that seems to be fine.

Comment: @vivek_23 I went into my php.ini file and changed `upload_max_filesize` from 2M to 21M. Then I told Wampserver64 to restart all services. When I tried uploading the file again it still wouldn't work. Interestingly, `ini_get()` says it is 21M.

Comment: Check what `post_max_size` is set to as well.

Comment: @Olimar I agree with `04FS`.  Sorry, I missed out on this, but you will also have to change `post_max_size`.

Comment: @04FS It turned out to be 8M, so I changed it to 0 to ignore limits and it worked! I'll post this as an answer to close this question.

Comment: This should rather be closed as a duplicate of [Change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size) then, instead of getting individually answered for the x-th time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the file I was trying to upload was too large. I had to go into my php.ini file and edit `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` to appropriate amounts. After restarting WAMP it worked fine.